# How do you increase text size programatically in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to increase the font size of a `TextView` at runtime if particular conditions are met.

I want to do it in a density independent way. I know the expression should be like`setTextSize(getTextSize() + 3 * factor);` though I don't know how to come up with `factor`.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the density factor is quite simple:

```
float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Comment: So you think `float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; setTextSize(getTextSize() + 3 * density);` will work?

Comment: 100% positive that it will

Answer (score 0):

When you look into

> setTextSize(float size)

you'll see this method.

```
public void setTextSize(float size) {
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
}
```

Which means that TextSize is adjusted based on the current density and your font preference.

or You can set your own setTextSize like

Value is raw pixels

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
```

Value is Device Independent

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size);
```

Value is a scaled pixel

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
```

Value is in points

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, size);
```

Value is in inches

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN, size);
```

Value is in millimeters

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, size);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer  but the problem is that I am not just setting the text size. I am increasing it and `getTextSize` returns the text size in pixels. Therefore I need something that works with screen densities.